# Webmodule project not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere-6.1, ibm-rad

We have IBM RAD 7 with websphere 1.6 version,when creating  webmodule project ,it is taking only java 5 and  @override annotation methods not working .Please provide hints.

Thanks,
Chaitu

Comment: Is it not working on interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

In Java 5 you cannot @override the methods of interfaces - only the methods of classes. It can be the reason...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Roman and K_K have stated, WebSphere 6.1 only supports up to Java5. Note also that [WebSphere 6.1 is going out of service at the end of September](http://www.ibm.com/software/websphere/support/lifecycle/).